# Property folder in payload has a value that does not match schema Graph Api

Tags: c#, json, microsoft-graph-api

the graph API request to create a folder in one drive is

```
   POST /me/drive/root/children
   Content-Type: application/json

    {
      "name": "New Folder",
      "folder": { },
      "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
    }
```

this but i dont undestand how to pass " { } " in httprequest content body .

My code:

```
 var tt = "{ }";
var jsonData = $@"{{ ""name"": ""{txtValue}"",""folder"":""{tt}""}}";
var body = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, 
"application/json"); 
apiRequest.Content = body;
apiRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new 
MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(apiRequest);
string d = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
```

but gives the error ""code": "BadRequest","message": "Property folder in payload has a value that does not match schema.","

Can anybody give me a hand ?

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason for not utilizing [`Microsoft Graph Client Library for .NET`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) for that matter?

Anyway the following example demonstrates how to [create a new folder in a drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_post_children?view=odsp-graph-online)  via `HttpClient`:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com");

    var folderPayload = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
       ["name"] = "Test Folder",
       ["folder"] = new { },
       ["@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior"] = "rename"
    };

   var requestContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folderPayload));
   requestContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
   var response = await client.PostAsync($"/v1.0/me/drive/root/children", requestContent);
   var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i was just experimenting .  Thanks a lot matet .